# ECC inverse modulo strange time execution

Tags: c, cryptography, biginteger

hi guys and excuse my english 
i developed a big integer function c :

```
#ifndef __BIGINTEGER_H
#define __BIGINTEGER_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "biginteger.h"
#define Maxbyte 19
typedef struct { uint32_t num[Maxbyte];
                 char sign ;
                 uint8_t lastblock ;} big_integer;


void init_biginteger(char *string_hex_number, big_integer *a);
big_integer Strassen_Multiplication(big_integer *a , big_integer *b );
big_integer add_biginteger(big_integer *a,big_integer *b );
big_integer sub_biginteger (big_integer *a,big_integer *b);
char  ABS_compare(big_integer *a , big_integer *b);
 void Lsh(big_integer *a , int shift, int bits);
 char div_mod(big_integer *a,big_integer *b,big_integer *Q,big_integer *R);
 char modulo(big_integer *a,big_integer *b,big_integer *c);
 char invers_modulo(big_integer *a ,big_integer *b,big_integer *c);
 void Rsh(big_integer *a , int shift,int bits);
  char zero(big_integer *a);
#endif
```

this is my functions :

```
static void char_to_hex(char s , uint32_t *byte){

switch(s){
    case '0' : *byte = 0x0000000; break;
    case '1' : *byte = 0x0000001; break;
    case '2' : *byte = 0x0000002; break;
    case '3' : *byte = 0x0000003; break;  
    case '4' : *byte = 0x0000004; break; 
    case '5' : *byte = 0x0000005; break; 
    case '6' : *byte = 0x0000006; break; 
    case '7' : *byte = 0x0000007; break; 
    case '8' : *byte = 0x0000008; break; 
    case '9' : *byte = 0x0000009; break;
    case 'A' : *byte = 0x000000a; break;
    case 'B' : *byte = 0x000000b; break;
    case 'C' : *byte = 0x000000c; break; 
    case 'D' : *byte = 0x000000d; break;
    case 'E' : *byte = 0x000000e; break;
    case 'F' : *byte = 0x000000f; break;

} 
}
static uint64_t get_cary_add(uint64_t a , uint64_t b ) {
    uint64_t c,c1,max=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    if(a>b){ c=a;
    c1=b;
    }else{c=b;
    c1=a;
    }
    if(max-c<c1){return 1;}else{


        return 0;}
}

static uint64_t safe_add64(uint64_t carry,uint64_t a, uint64_t b){
    if(carry==0){
        return a+b;}else{
            uint64_t a1=0,b1=0,c1=0;
            uint64_t a2=a,b2=b,s=0;
        a1= (a2 & 0x8000000000000000)>>63;
        b1= (b2 & 0x8000000000000000)>>63;
        a2=a2 & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
        b2=b2 & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
        s= a2+b2;
        c1=(uint64_t)(s)>>63;
        s=s & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
        c1=(uint64_t) (a1+b1+c1)<<63;
        c1= (uint64_t)(s)| c1  ;
        return c1;

        }

    }

static uint32_t safe_add32(uint32_t carry,uint32_t a, uint32_t b){

    if(carry==0){
        return a+b;}else{
        uint32_t a1=0,b1=0,c1=0,s=0;
         uint32_t a2=a,b2=b;
        a1= (uint32_t) (a2 & 0x80000000) >> 31;
        b1= (uint32_t)((b2 & 0x80000000) >> 31);
        a2=a2 & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        b2=b2 & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        s= a2+b2;
        c1=(uint32_t)(s)>>31;
        s= s &  0x7FFFFFFF;
        c1=(uint32_t)(a1+b1+c1)<<31;
        c1= (uint32_t)(s)| c1  ;
        return c1;

        }

    }




static uint32_t get_carry_add(uint32_t a , uint32_t b ) {
    uint32_t c,c1,max=0xFFFFFFFF;
    if(a>b){ c=a;
    c1=b;
    }else{c=b;
    c1=a;
    }
    if(max-c<c1){return 1;}else{


        return 0;}
}

char  ABS_compare(big_integer *a , big_integer *b){
    int i=a->lastblock,k=-1;
    if(a->lastblock>b->lastblock){return 1;}
    else if (b->lastblock > a->lastblock){return 2;} 
    else{  

        while(k==-1){
        if(a->num[i]>b->num[i]){k=1;}
        else if(b->num[i]>a->num[i]){k=2;}
        else if( i==0 && k==-1){k=0;}
        i=i-1;
        }
         }
    return k;
}

void Lsh(big_integer *a , int shift,int bits){
    int i=0,j=0,k;
    //80000000;
    uint32_t temp=0;
    i=bits/32-1;
    k=i;
    for(j=0;j<shift;j++){

    if(i==0){
    a->num[0]=(a->num[0]<<1);

    }else{
   i=i-1;
    a->num[i+1]=(a->num[i+1]<<1);
    for(;i>=0;i--){
        temp=(a->num[i] & 0x80000000);
        temp=uint32_t(temp>>31);
        a->num[i]=(a->num[i]<<1);

        a->num[i+1]= a->num[i+1] | temp;

    }
    }

    }
    j=0;
    while(a->num[k]==0 && j==0){
        if(k!=0){
            k=k-1;}else {j=1;}

    }
    a->lastblock=k;

}


void Rsh(big_integer *a , int shift,int bits){
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    //80000000;
    uint32_t temp=0;
    i=bits/32-1;

    for(j=0;j<shift;j++){

    if(i==0){
    a->num[0]=(a->num[0]>>1);

    }else{

    //a->num[i+1]=(a->num[i+1]<<1);
    for(k=0;k<=i;k++){
        temp=(a->num[k+1] & 0x00000001);
        temp=uint32_t(temp<<31);
        a->num[k]=(a->num[k]>>1);

        a->num[k]= a->num[k] | temp;

    }
    }

    }
    j=0;
    while(a->num[k]==0 && j==0){
        if(k!=0){
            k=k-1;}else {j=1;}

    }
    a->lastblock=k;

}



void init_biginteger(char *string_hex_number, big_integer *a){
int i = strlen(string_hex_number)-1;
memset(a->num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));
uint32_t byte=0;
int j=0,k=0;
for(i;i>=0;i--){
    if(string_hex_number[i]=='-'){a->sign=-1;}else{
    char_to_hex(string_hex_number[i],&byte);
  //  byte = string_hex_number[i] - 0x30;
    byte = (byte << j);
    a->num[k]=byte | a->num[k];
    j=j+4;
    if(j==32){
    k=k+1;
    j=0;
    }
    }

    }
if(string_hex_number[0]!='-') {a->sign = 1;}
if(k!=0){
    if(a->num[k]==0){k=k-1;}}

a->lastblock = k;
}

big_integer add_biginteger(big_integer *a,big_integer *b ){

    big_integer tempa,tempb,result,tempo;
    memset(result.num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));
    tempa=*a;
    tempb=*b;
    int k,i;
    uint32_t carry=0,carry1=0,carry2=0;
    if(tempa.lastblock>tempb.lastblock){
        k=tempa.lastblock+1;
    }else { k=tempb.lastblock+1;}

    if(tempa.sign == tempb.sign){
        for(i=0;i<=k;i++){
            carry=(uint32_t)get_carry_add(tempa.num[i],tempb.num[i]);
            tempo.num[i]=safe_add32(carry,tempa.num[i],tempb.num[i]);
            //tempo.num[i]=(uint32_t)tempa.num[i] + tempb.num[i];
            carry2=(uint32_t)get_carry_add(tempo.num[i],carry1);
            //carry=+carry;
            result.num[i] = safe_add32(carry2, tempo.num[i] , carry1);
            carry1=carry2+carry;
            //carry1=carry;
        //carry1=carry+ get_carry_add(result.num[i],carry);

        } 

        while(result.num[i]==0){ i=i-1;  }
        result.lastblock=i;
        result.sign = tempa.sign;
        return result;
    }else if (tempb.sign==-1){
        tempb.sign=1;
        result = sub_biginteger(&tempa,&tempb);
        return result;
        }else {
            tempa.sign=1;
            result = sub_biginteger(&tempb,&tempa);
        return result;
        }





}


big_integer sub_biginteger (big_integer *a,big_integer *b){
    big_integer result,tempa,tempb;
    memset(result.num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));
    tempa = *a;
    tempb=*b;
    int i,k;
    if(b->sign==-1 && a->sign==1){
        tempb.sign=1;
        result=add_biginteger(&tempa,&tempb);
        return result;  
    }else if(a->sign==-1 && b->sign==1){
        tempb.sign=-1;
        result=add_biginteger(&tempa,&tempb);
        return result;
    }else{


    k= ABS_compare(&tempa,&tempb);
    if(k==0){          
        result.lastblock=0;
        result.sign=1;
        return result;
    }else if(k==1){
        result.sign=1;
    }else { 
        result=tempb;
        tempb=tempa;
        tempa=result;

        result.sign=-1;}

    uint64_t tempo,temp,carry=0;
    for(i=0;i<tempa.lastblock+1;i++){
        if((uint64_t)tempa.num[i]< (uint64_t) (tempb.num[i]+carry)){

        temp=(uint64_t)tempa.num[i];
        tempo=(uint64_t)tempb.num[i]+carry;
        temp=(uint64_t)(temp+0x100000000 - tempo);
        result.num[i]=(uint32_t)temp;

        carry=1;
        }else{
            result.num[i]=tempa.num[i]-tempb.num[i]-carry;      
        carry=0;
        }}

    }

    while(result.num[i]==0){i=i-1;}
    result.lastblock=i;
    return result;

}



big_integer Strassen_Multiplication(big_integer *a , big_integer *b ){
    big_integer result ;
    big_integer tempa = *a;
    big_integer tempb = *b;
    uint32_t rest=0;
    uint64_t div=0,carry=0,carry1;
    int k,k1,i,j ,j2;
    if(a->lastblock > b->lastblock){ 
        k =tempa.lastblock+1;
        k1=tempb.lastblock+1;
        result= tempa;
        tempa=tempb;
        tempb=result;
    }else{
            k=tempb.lastblock+1;
            k1=tempa.lastblock+1;

        }

   uint64_t **arg=NULL;
   arg= (uint64_t ** ) calloc (k*2+3, sizeof(uint64_t *));
   if(arg==NULL){
   exit(1);
   }
for(i=0;i<k+3;i++){
    arg[i]= (uint64_t * ) calloc (k*2+3, sizeof(uint64_t));
  if(arg[i]==NULL){
   exit(1);
   }

}

j=0;

for(i=0;i<k1;i++){
    j2=0;

    for(j=i;j<k+i;j++){

        arg[i][j]=(uint64_t) tempb.num[j2]*tempa.num[i];
    // tab3[i][j]=arg3[i][j];
    j2=j2+1;
    }

}
memset(result.num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));


for(j=0;j<(k1+k);j++){
for(i=0;i<k1;i++){
    carry=(uint64_t)carry+get_cary_add(arg[k+1][j],arg[i][j]  );
    arg[k+1][j]=(uint64_t)safe_add64 (carry,arg[i][j],arg[k+1][j]);

    }
carry1=get_cary_add(arg[k+1][j],div);
carry=carry+carry1;
arg[k+1][j]=(uint64_t)safe_add64(carry1,arg[k+1][j],div);
 div= (uint64_t) (arg[k+1][j] / 0x100000000) | (carry * 0x100000000) ;
 rest=(uint32_t)(arg[k+1][j] % 0x100000000);
 result.num[j]=(uint32_t)rest;
 carry=0;
}

result.sign = tempa.sign * tempb.sign;
while(result.num[j]==0 && j!=0){j=j-1;}
result.lastblock = j;
for(i=0;i<k*2+3;i++){
    free(arg[i]);}
free(arg);



    return result;
}







char div_mod(big_integer *a,big_integer *b,big_integer *Q,big_integer *R){
    int k;

    k=ABS_compare(a ,b);
    if(b->lastblock==0 && b->num[0]==0) {return -1;}
    else if(k==2){memset(R->num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));
                  memset(Q->num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));

                  Q->lastblock=0;
                  Q->sign=1;
                  *R=*a;
                  R->sign=a->sign;
                 }
    else if(k==0){memset(R->num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));
                  memset(Q->num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));
                  Q->num[0]=1;
                  Q->lastblock=0;
                  Q->sign = a->sign * b->sign;
                  R->sign=1;
                  R->lastblock=0;
                  R->num[0]=0;

    }

    else { memset(R->num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));
           memset(Q->num,NULL,Maxbyte*sizeof(uint32_t));
           uint8_t lb=a->lastblock;
           big_integer tempa,tempb;
           tempa=*a;
           tempb=*b;
           tempb.lastblock = tempa.lastblock;
           R->lastblock = tempa.lastblock;
           Q->lastblock = tempa.lastblock;
           int i = tempa.lastblock,size = (lb+1)*32,j=0;

           uint32_t bits= 0x80000000,h;
           for(;i>=0;i--){
               for(j=31;j>=0;j--){
               Lsh(R,1,size);
               R->lastblock = lb;
               h=(tempa.num[i]<<(31-j));
               h=h>>31;
              // byte = byte & 0x01;
               R->num[0]=uint32_t(R->num[0] | h);
               if(ABS_compare(R ,&tempb)!=2){
               *R=sub_biginteger(R,&tempb );
               R->lastblock=lb;
               tempb.lastblock=lb;
               Q->num[i]=  Q->num[i] | ( bits>>(31-j));
               }
               }
           }
           Q->sign= a->sign * b->sign;
           R->sign= a->sign;
           j= lb;
           while(Q->num[j]==0 && j!=0){j=j-1;}
           Q->lastblock = j;
           j= lb;
           while(R->num[j]==0 && j!=0){j=j-1;}
           R->lastblock = j;


    }


return 1;
}


char modulo(big_integer *a,big_integer *b,big_integer *c){

    big_integer temp;
    char k;
    k=div_mod(a,b,&temp,c);
    if(k==-1){ return -1;}else{
        if(a->sign==-1){
            *c=add_biginteger(c ,b);}
    }
    return 1;

}

 char zero(big_integer *a){
    if(a->sign==-1){ return -1;       }else {
        /*int i=0,j=0;
        while(i!=a->lastblock && j==0){
            if(a->num[i]!=0){j=1;}
            i=i+1;

        }
        if(j=1){return 1;}else{
            return 0;}*/
        if(a->lastblock >0){return 1;}else{
            if(a->num[0]==0){return 0;}else{
                return 1;}
        }


}
}

 char invers_modulo(big_integer *a ,big_integer *b,big_integer *c){

    if( b->sign==-1){ return -1;}

     big_integer tempa=*a,tempb=*b;
    tempa.sign=1;
     big_integer d,t,x,v,tempo,d1;

    init_biginteger("1",&d);
    init_biginteger("0",&v);
    int conteur=0;

    //clock_t pp;
 //pp = clock();
    while(zero(&tempa)==1){
    x=tempa;
    //conteur = conteur +1;
    /*if(conteur==57){
    conteur = conteur;
    }*/
    //printf("%i \n", conteur);
    div_mod(&tempb,&tempa,&t,&tempo);
    tempa=tempo;
    tempb=x;
    x=d;
    d1=Strassen_Multiplication(&t ,&x );
    d= sub_biginteger (&v,&d1);
    v=x;
    }
    //printf("%i \n",conteur);
    // pp= clock() - pp; 
  //printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",pp,(((double)pp)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    tempb=*b;
    modulo(&v,&tempb,&tempo);
    if(v.sign==-1){
    modulo(&add_biginteger(&v,&tempb),&tempb,&tempo); }
    *c=tempo;

    //printf("%i \n",conteur);

return 1;
```

}

now the prblem is for 256 bits intger inverse modulo take 0.005 s thats too much ECC cryptography cuz in scalar multiplication i will repeated at least 256 time in double and add algorithm

i have done some tests about time this a test main about 10k time it finish in 0.69 s:

```
#include "biginteger.h"
#include "ECC.h"
#include <time.h>
void main(){

    clock_t t;
 t = clock();
    int p=1;

    big_integer a,b,c,r,q,a1,b1;
    ECC_domaine_parameter domain;
init_biginteger("580EC00D856434334CEF3F31ECAED4965B12AE37FA47055B1965C7B134EE45D0",  &a);
init_biginteger("FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", &b);
while(p!=0 ){  div_mod(&b,&a,&q,&r);
               c=Strassen_Multiplication(&a , &b );
                c=sub_biginteger(&a,&b );

         a1=a;
         b1=b;
         b1=a;
         a1=b;
         a1=b1;
         p=p+1;
     if(p==10001){
         printf("end %i \n",p);
         p=0;}} 
 t = clock() - t; 
  printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,(((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
}
```

now the inverse modulo function core for same 2 256 bit integer:

```
char invers_modulo(big_integer *a ,big_integer *b,big_integer *c){

    if( b->sign==-1){ return -1;}

     big_integer tempa=*a,tempb=*b;
    tempa.sign=1;
     big_integer d,t,x,v,tempo,d1;

    init_biginteger("1",&d);
    init_biginteger("0",&v);
    int conteur=0;
while(zero(&tempa)==1){ div_mod(&tempb,&tempa,&t,&tempo);
    tempa=tempo;
    tempb=x;
    x=d;
    d1=Strassen_Multiplication(&t ,&x );
    d= sub_biginteger (&v,&d1);
    v=x;
    }tempb=*b;
    modulo(&v,&tempb,&tempo);
    if(v.sign==-1){
    modulo(&add_biginteger(&v,&tempb),&tempb,&tempo); }
    *c=tempo;



return 1;
}
```

for inverse modulo it take 150 time inside while this is test main just execute invers modulo 300 time  :

```
 void main(){

    clock_t t;
 t = clock();
    int p=1;

    big_integer a,b,c,r,q,a1,b1;
    ECC_domaine_parameter domain;
init_biginteger("580EC00D856434334CEF3F31ECAED4965B12AE37FA47055B1965C7B134EE45D0",  &a);
init_biginteger("FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", &b);
 while(p!=0 ){ invers_modulo(&a ,&b,&c);

         a1=a;
         b1=b;
         b1=a;
         a1=b;
         a1=b1;
         p=p+1;
     if(p==300){
         printf("end %i \n",p);
         p=0;}}
 t = clock() - t; 
  printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,(((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
}
```

inverse modulo for 300 time take 1.422 seconde more than executing division sub and multiplication 10k time even the core of inverse modulo is build with same division and sub and multiplication functions and for this number it just do 150 time inside while help plz why

Answer (score 0):

Inversion is a very intensive operation. There are several optimizations you can do, for example minimizing the amount of inversions you have to use or optimizing the inversion algorithm. To optimize the algorithm, you can implement the Itoh-Tsujii Inversion for example.

To decrease the amount of inversions you need, you can go from representing points in the affine coordinate system to converting them to projective representation. For ECC systems, an often used version of projective coordinates are the so called López-Dahab coordinates and operations on these.